# Assign Each Mysql Column As a Variable And Convert The Data Into a String

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to build a news page for my site. At the moment I'm trying to get the page to retrieve all of the rows in the table then split each column into variables and convert the data into a string.

Here's an example of what I mean.

News Post 1:

```
ID: 1
POST TITLE: Welcome
POST DATE: 03/10/2018 
POST AUTHOR: Administrator
MESSAGE: Lorem.
```

News Post 2:

```
ID: 2 
POST TITLE: Goodbye
POST DATE: 03/10/2018
POST AUTHOR: Administrator
MESSAGE: Ipsum.
```

That's how the data is represented in the table.

I would like to put each column into a variable, so when I put the data into a news box. Each news item displays in the same format. Like a forum. When I retrieve the data from the database it gives this:

`array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> int(1) [0]=> int(1) ["posttitle"]=> string(37) "Welcome" [1]=> string(37) "Welcome" ["postdate"]=> string(10) "2018-10-02" [2]=> string(10) "2018-10-02" ["postauthor"]=> string(27) "Administrator)" [3]=> string(27) "Administrator)" ["message"]=> string(12) "Lorem" [4]=> string(12) "Lorem" } }`

And this is the code I currently have:

```
<?php

$pdo->beginTransaction();
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news");
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll();

$pdo->commit();

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove those indexed duplicates, use this:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then your results be:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["posttitle"]=> string(37) "Welcome" ["postdate"]=> string(10) "2018-10-02" ["postauthor"]=> string(27) "Administrator)" ["message"]=> string(12) "Lorem" } }
```

Read this for better understanding:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I ended up using FETCH_OBJ. Which then only gave `id = 1`. `posttitle = welcome` ect...